# If I deploy my Twitch bot made in python on Heroku using github when the variables get edited while being used does that reflect in the github code?

Tags: python, github, heroku

I have a variable and a .txt file that are updated via commands in Twitch chat. The bot is made in python. One being a counter that gets added to every time someone does a specific command. Does the counter variable get updated within the code on Github that I am able to see it when checking the code?

Another command adds new words to a .txt file, when someone performs the command to add something would that get added to the .txt file on Github as well or only within the heroku app.

I have tried performing commands but it seems like when I update the counter or add to the .txt it doesn't reflect in github. Is there a way to make it reflect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those resources are generated or updated during the execution of your program (here, an Heroku application), which means, by default, their updates are not tracked under source control (in the Heroku app execution environment context), so not visible in GitHub.

You would need, from your application to call a [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions) (pipeline executed on GitHub side), like [action-update-file](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/update-files-on-github), in order to fetch (curl) and then update your files in your GitHub repository.
See "[How to trigger a Github action with an HTTP request](https://dev.to/rikurouvila/how-to-trigger-a-github-action-with-an-htt-request-545)" (from [Riku Rouvila](https://github.com/rikukissa)) for a practical example of calling a GitHub Action from a program.

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back. I read through the pages but I'm still confused on how to go about using action-update-file to update the variables and txt file within the Github .py code. When I commit changes to the variable and txt files in Github it automaticallt pushes to heroku, I was hoping there was a way to do that but in reverse(server to github)

Comment: My current set up is similar to 'var1 = 0', and then there is a method that increases by 1 whenever actions/commands are performed. Then there is a txt file with words and I have a method that the user can call a command to add a word that can be accessed later. Basically don't want to lose the words and var whenever the server goes on and off for various reasons or if I want to move it to a different server later.

Comment: @ZeaR The idea is to call, through a curl (which can be done in python), the specific GitHub Action which would update that file, provided that action can call a script (versioned in your repository) able to fetch from the Heroku app the updated file.